# I get Redifinition of 'row' error, and 'setText' is deprecated error..Im not sure how to fix it. here is the code

Tags: ios4, uitableview

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];{
    cell.text = [capitulosArray objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
    }

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];{
    cell.text = [capitulos2Array objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
    }
}
```

Im here to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to think that `NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];{ ... }` is something like C#'s `using`. It's not, it's just like the similar construct in C. So you are declaring the local variable "row" twice, and the compiler is warning you about it.

As for the warning that "setText" is deprecated, that's because it is. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/text). You'll most likely want to use `cell.textLabel.text` instead.

Comment: ok. so cell.textLable.text worked. but I can fix the doble declaration because what im trying to do is to have multiples cell in my tableview and each cell to open a different textview. how can i do that?